# verbs: `ibv_req_notify_cq`, can it miss an event?

Tags: rdma

Consider this code:

```cpp
cq = ibv_create_cq(...);

while(true)
{
  ibv_req_notify_cq(cq, 0); // 1.
  
  ibv_get_cq_event(...);

  // Empty the events
  while(ibv_poll_cq(...) > 0)
  {
    process_event(...);
  }

  ibv_ack_cq_events(...); // 2.
}
```

My question is the following: Between `2.` and `1.` (of the next iteration), if a CQE is generated, aren't we gonna miss it, because `ibv_req_notify_cq()` will empty the CQ? And so the event is forever "lost" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are mixed concepts here.

*ibv_req_notify_cq* tells the CQ it should produce an event, when the new CQE arrives

*ibv_get_cq_event* - blocks until event arrives

*ibv_poll_cq* - polls for completions, effectively emptying it, when using in a loop like in this example

*ibv_ack_cq_events* - acknowledges the event

So the *req_notify_cq* is a one-time action - as a result only one event will be produced.

When the event arrives there might be n-CQEs that are polled, but since you didn't re-arm the CQ, you do not expect any other events to arrive for that CQ.

If there are CQEs generated after the event arrives, and before the *ibv_poll_cq* loop finishes, they will be polled with that loop, and they will not generate any other event.

If there are CQEs generated after the *ibv_poll_cq* loop (for instance during *ibv_ack_cq_events*), they will not be polled, and they will generate and event only after the CQ is armed again in next iteration.
Arming the CQ when there is CQE waiting for being polled is fine and should work properly (at least for Intel RDMA nics).